# Unable to map <Super>+M

Tags: 16.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> mapped to `Maximize window horizontally` in my keyboard shortcuts, but it still opens the calendar. I have also set `<Super>+V` to paste, but this also opens my calendar.

I can't find where <kbd>Super</kbd> is being mapped to the calendar anywhere. Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can make it stop?

Note that I amusing `gnome` with `Ubuntu 16.04LTS` and the `gdm3` display manager if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This problem annoyed me too. (I like my custom hotkeys.)

I found this setting buried way deep in the system **[dconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf)** settings under `/org/gnome/shell/keybindings` on my system.

You'll need to install [dconf-editor](https://packages.debian.org/sid/dconf-editor)

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then you'll need to search for "calendar" until you find the related setting. 
*(Note: I'm using **Ubuntu 17.10 / gnome-shell window manager**. This will likely be different under your system, but it should exist somewhere.)*

(If you're using gnome-shell window manager: look under `/org/gnome/shell/keybindings` for key `toggle-message-tray`.

Here's what it looked like on my system.)
[image]

#### To change the default hotkey settings:

1. Turn off the "Use default value" setting.
2. Set "Custom value" to "". (That's two empty quotes)
3. Now you should be able to use your custom keybindings.

Good luck, please post back here if this worked (or if you found the setting in 16.04)